# How to get the result after create hyper-v snapshot in wmi

Tags: c#, wmi

1. I can not get the result after create hyper-v snapshot on winserver 2012r2, it means I don't know the instanceID of created snapshot.
2. I've see the method `CreateSnapshot` of the class `Msvm_VirtualSytemSnapshotService`, its input params include `ResultingSnapshot` that reference `CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData`,and its output params include `ResultingSnapshot` too.
3. I create a `CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData` instance to invoke the method `CreateSnapshot`. When I running the program,it tells me

> Invalid method Parameter(s)

If I invoke method `CreateSnapshot` without `ResultingSnapshot`, I create success.

Please give me some suggestion!

## The code:

```
    ManagementObject virtualSystemService = Utility.GetServiceObject(scope,"Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService");

    ManagementBaseObject inParams = virtualSystemService.GetMethodParameters("CreateSnapshot");
    
    ManagementPath resultingSettingDataPath = new ManagementPath("CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData");
    ManagementClass serviceClass = new ManagementClass(scope, resultingSettingDataPath, null);
    ManagementObject resultingSettingData = serviceClass.CreateInstance();
    
    ManagementObject vm = Utility.GetTargetComputer(vmName, scope);
    
    inParams.SetPropertyValue("AffectedSystem", vm.Path.Path);
    
    inParams.SetPropertyValue("SnapshotType", snapshotType);

    inParams.SetPropertyValue("ResultingSnapshot", serviceClass.createInstance());

    //inParams.SetPropertyValue("SnapshotSettings", null);
    // inParams.SetPropertyValue("Job", null);
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = virtualSystemService.InvokeMethod("CreateSnapshot", inParams, null);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the job object and the ResultingSnapshot object from the outParams and not set it as input parameters,
After calling the CreateSnapshot method  get the Job object and check its' status, if the Job completed then you can get the ResultingSnapshot object from the outParams.

```
bool snapShotCreated = false;
if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == 4096) // Job in progress
{
    // Get the job object to continue querying
    string jobPath = outParams["job"].ToString();
    ManagementObject job = new ManagementObject(jobPath);

    // TODO: You now have the job object, query it until the job completed.

}
else if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == 0)
{
    // job completed
    snapShotCreated = true;
}
else
{
    // Error 
}

if (snapShotCreated)
{
    string resultingSystemPath = outParams["ResultingSnapshot"].ToString();
    ManagementObject resultingSystem = new ManagementObject(resultingSystemPath);
}
```

Let me know if it worked...

Comment: If that's the case then what is the significance of the INOUT param ResultingSnapshot ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I have seen the JobStatus and it is completed but still, the Resulting Snapshot is NULL.